# How to do smooth transition effect on fragment android

Tags: android, animation, fragment

I am applying In and Out transition effect while changing fragment by using `setCustomAnimations`

method.I have three fragment two of them contain only background image and one fragment contain three gallery view.

Now while applying transition effect on these fragment.The fragment which contains gallery views appling transition effect slowly with respect to remaining fragement.

How can solve this to have to feel three fragments with same smoothness.
See my code how i am applying transition to fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction previewTransition=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
previewTransition.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.leftin,R.anim.leftout);
PreviewFragment preview=new PreviewFragment();
previewTransition.replace(R.id.fragcontainer,preview,"Preview");
previewTransition.commit();
```

And this is Adapter getView() method code

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if(imagePaths.size() == 0)
        {
            return getCustomView();
        }
        int itemPos;
        try {
            itemPos = (position % imagePaths.size());
            if(images[itemPos] == null){
                String path = imagePaths.get(itemPos);
                BitmapDrawable drawable =new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path));
                drawable.setAntiAlias(true);
                images[itemPos] = drawable;
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            return getCustomView();
        }
        view=convertView;
        if(view==null)
        view = getCustomView();
        ImageView containerImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.container);
        containerImage.setImageDrawable(images[itemPos]);
        return view;
    }
    private View getCustomView()
    {
        View imgLayout=(RelativeLayout)inflaterLayout.inflate(R.layout.conainers,null);
        return imgLayout;
    }
```

Thanks in Adavance.

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the problem. Is the transition animation not smooth or is there problems with the smoothness of the gallery fragment?

Comment: there is a problem with gallery fragment only remaining two fragment are smooth

Comment: because of gallery view only smoothness reducing

Comment: But is it the transition to next fragment from the gallery fragment or is it just the smoothness of the gallery fragment that is an issue?

Comment: it is trasition from frament1 to grallery fragment

Comment: In other words its the instantiation of your gallery that is causing the lag. What happens in the onCreate of the gallery fragment? Do you do a lot on the main thread, download images from web etc.? Post your onCreate() onResume code for further help...

Comment: No i am loading local images from file system in adapter getview method

Comment: i edited my question please check